# cbind different length of data frames based on column

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
name stock_1 stock_2
A      11      12
B       9       2
C       1       3

df2
name stock_1
D     2
E     4
```

expected output:

```
 name stock_1 stock_2
    A      11      12
    B       9       2
    C       1       3
    D     2        NA
    E     4        NA
```

the name and stock_1 names of columns. I try to cbind the 2 df but it is not working. Is there any efficient way?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `dplyr::full_join()` :

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2)
df3
  name stock_1 stock_2
1    A      11      12
2    B       9       2
3    C       1       3
4    D       2      NA
5    E       4      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `plyr`:

```
plyr::rbind.fill(df1,df2)

 name stock_1 stock_2
 A    11      12     
 B     9       2     
 C     1       3     
 D     2      NA     
 E     4      NA
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: great answer! I like this one!